# Excel returning a False response

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

=IF(B12<>"",(IF(U12="Subscription","Subscribe",IF(U12="T.E.H.","Subscribe",IF(U12="ESA","Subscribe",IF(U12="Perpetual","Buy",IF(U12=" "," ")))))))

I get a "False" value in the cell with this formula in it when the value in U12 is not one of the options and I want to get a blank
Appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: Change this: `IF(U12=" ", " ")` to this: `IF(U12=" ", " ", "")`.  However, I don't think this is exactly right.  Is the entire purpose of this clause to generate the blank?  Or are you really checking to see if the U12 = " "?

Comment: There's no Else clause on your very first IF( function. When B12 is missing or blank nothing is delivered.  How about making it `IF(B12=""," ", ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `IF(U12=" ", " ")` to this: `IF(U12=" ", " ", "")`.  Here's a demo in Google Sheets, but the formulas are the same.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10iFqq0PNt9VhGKMPLCxsI1df0x4nDSxCaCGSdEEktO8/edit#gid=0

However, I don't think this is exactly right.  For one thing, it looks like this clause:

```
IF(U12=" ", " ")
```

is only there to try to generate the blank you are looking for.  If that's the case, then change it to:

```
IF(U12=" ", " ", "")
```

However, I think I would probably use some array constants, something like this:

```
=IF(B12<>"", CHOOSE(SUM(--(U12={"Subscription","T.E.H","ESA"})) + IF(U12="Perpetual", 2) +1, "", "Subscribe", "Buy"))
```

To break this down a little, let me reformat so it's easier to see:

```
=IF(
  B12 <> "", 
  CHOOSE(
    SUM(--(U12={"Subscription","T.E.H","ESA"})) + 
    IF(U12="Perpetual", 2) + 1
    "", "Subscribe", "Buy"
  )
)
```

I'm going to use CHOOSE, which takes an index number N and a list of choices, and it returns the Nth element in the choice list.  To generate the index, I'm going to use a couple of techniques.  First look at this:

```
U12 = {"Subscription", "T.E.H", "ESA"})
```

This is going to test U12 against all of the choices in the list, and return an array of TRUE/FALSE values.  If U12 matches any of the elements in the array constant, then one of those values will be TRUE.  We use -- to coerce that array from TRUE/FALSE to 0/1, and then we use SUM to get the array into a single value.  It will either be 0 if U12 doesn't match any of the options, or 1 if it does.

Then I'm going to use a standard IF to check if U12 = Perpetual, and return 2 if it does.  Adding that result to the previous sum will give us a final number that is either 0, 1 or 2.

CHOOSE is 1 indexed, meaning that it expects the index to be 1 or greater, so we add 1 to the number we just generated and pass it to CHOOSE along with a list of options.

The advantage here is that if the Subscribe options change you can just change the list, instead of having to alter a bunch of nested IFs.  Also, if you need to support multiple buy options, you can do it with a similar construction:

```
SUM(--(U12 = {"Subscription", "T.E.H", "ESA"})) +
IF(SUM(--(U12 = {"Perpetual", "Buy Now"})), 2) + 1
```

and if you needed to add return values just keep extending:

```
CHOOSE(
  SUM(--(U12 = {"Subscription", "T.E.H", "ESA"})) +
  IF(SUM(--(U12 = {"Perpetual", "Buy Now"})), 2) +
  IF(SUM(--(U12 = {"Release", "Dropping"})), 3) + 1,
  "", "Subscribe", "Buy", "Sell"
)
```

If you think this is something that might need to be maintained or the options might change, I would set it up like this, as opposed to nested IFs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a little clearer?

```
=IF(B12=""," ",IfError(VLookup(U12,{"ESA","Subscribe";"Perpetual","Buy";"Subscription",Subscribe";"T.E.H.","Subscribe"},2,false)," "))
```

This is really just a table lookup, hence the use of VLookup.  The lookup array is a two dimensional array in curly brackets - the commas and semicolons are very important for defining a 2x4 array for VLookup.  The IFError function tells how to return your desired " " result if the lookup fails.